# rails multi-select dropdown using chosen-rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a multi-select dropdown using rails, html and chosen-rails gem.

```
<%= f.input :employee_id, as: :select, :collection => current_employee.get_employees, :multiple => true %>
```

This is how it is appearing in UI.

[image]

My JS code :

```
$('#reports_employee_id').chosen({
      allow_single_deselect: true,
      max_selected_options: 25,
      placeholder_text_multiple: " ",
      no_results_text: 'No results matched'
    });
```

What I want is that, I want to add the email of the employees under the employee names in the dropdown only and not in the selected tile. Something like this :

[image]

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not so much a ruby-on-rails question as it is a "chosen.js" question. If you want more people to look at it, maybe try to limit it to that.

Comment: That being said: I think chosen.js is somewhat limited in what you can do, I don't think this is supported. Take a look at "select2.js", it's more versatile.

Comment: Can confirm select2 will cut it just fine.

Comment: It would be better if you could post some link to examples. I am using select2 now but still am unable to have the dropbox like how i intend eg: with the emails appended below the usernames